# How to use SourceTree with multiple repositories?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'd like to be able to use SourceTree with more than one Git repository. Have tried adding two repositories to the Repository Settings, which is fine in that it shows the remote repositories and all their remote branches below REMOTES in the left navigation pane:

```
BRANCHES
  staging
  sourcebranchname
REMOTES
> database-oracle
    staging
    dbbranchname1
> source
    staging
    sourcebranchname2
```

However, it isn't showing all the local branches that have been created for both repositories. In the example above, there is a branch named "staging" for both repositories but only one is shown under "BRANCHES". Is there a way of dealing with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are confusing remotes and repositories.
Remotes are just different servers with the same repository. For example if you are using a private git server and github for the same project, so you can push to both.
You have two separate repositories (projects)
To add a new repository, click on `File -> New / Clone` or `File -> Open`
You can than open the two repositories in two windows.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense. I now have one tab for each repository and just have the repository name for each set to "origin" rather than "source" and "database-oracle". The only bit I still don't quite understand is why SourceTree allows you to set more than one Remote repository path for a single repository - but I guess there must be a good reason.

Comment: There are some situations where multiple remotes are quite useful. One very common situation is github, where you want to have on remote point to the original codebase and one to your version. So you can pull changes from upstream. You can read more about this here https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/